# Dart character encoding in http request

Tags: flutter, dart, character-encoding

Just learning Flutter and running into this issue when trying to call an API:

```
final response = await http.get(
  Uri.https(apiBaseUrl, apiBaseEndpoint + "/tasks"),
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + apiKey,
  },
);

print(response.body);
```

Part of my response contains `Ä°ftar` and it's supposed to be `İftar`. I imagine it's some encoding problem? `curl` gives me back the response with the proper characters.

Basically: is this a text encoding problem? If so, how do I fix my request?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, after a little bit more digging on the [http docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/) I realized it wasn't in how I made my request that needed to change, but how I handled the response. I was doing

`final decodedJson = json.decode(response.body);`

and I should've been doing:

`final decodedJson = json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));`

That has solved my issue!